# How do we express we take the net off the ring of a basketball net?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

A simple basketball net for children includes a ring and a net. You have to put the net "**on**" the ring (I am not sure "**on**" is the correct preposition here) by sliding the rope of the net "**in**" or "**into**" the holes or gaps of the rings (I am not sure "**in**" or "**into**" is the correct preposition here)

**How do we express we take the net off the ring?**

For example, "**slide the net out of the holes or gaps to take it off the ring**"

Comment: Why do you think that is wrong - all looks fine to me.

Comment: You could say "unclip the net" or "unlace the net" depending on the method of fastening.

Comment: Or simply 'take the net off' (there is probably no need to specify the exact technique for doing so in ordinary conversation).

Comment: ***untie** the net? **unthread** the net? **undo** the net?* Any and all the alternatives here would probably "pass muster". There might even be domain-specific more idiomatic usages (maybe ***knock down** the net*, modelled on *knock down the wicket* for dismantling and packing away the equipment after a game of cricket).

Comment: **unhook** and **detach** are also possibilities